# How to add a string to a new column instead of to a new row?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a CSV file that I want to add a string to but into a new column. I have a list of strings where I'm adding a new string onto it using the "Add" method which looks like "output.Add(stringInQuestion);".

I've already tried adding "," commas to the front of the string like so: "output.Add(,,,stringInQuestion);" as well as adding the original list to it in this way, "output.Add(output + stringInQuestion);". This might be redundant, but I thought I would give it a shot.

```
///////////////////////////////Block1
var output = new List<string>();

     foreach (var contact in contacts)
     {
       Console.WriteLine($"{contact.FirstName},{contact.LastName},{contact.EmailAddress}");
       output.Add($"{contact.FirstName},{contact.LastName},{contact.EmailAddress},{contact.FirstName}-{contact.EmailAddress}-{contact.LastName}");
     }
//////////////////////////////////Block2    
output.Add(encryptedTextAsBase64);
```

The first block of code is what introduces the list of strings called "output". It takes a CSV file, splits the strings into segments, and then reorders them as needed. After this process, I join the strings together using the "string.Join" method, and proceed to encrypt the resulting string. The problem is getting the encrypted data (string) onto a new column instead of a new row.

The CSV file opened in Excel should look like the example below:

```
First Name | Last Name | Email Address | Frist Name-Email Address-Last Name| randomgibberishencryptedstringasdkfajsd9f80897gajsbdlkjb23iu8asdf...etc.
```

Treat the vertical bar as a new column.
The text writes out like this instead:

```
First Name | Last Name | Email Address | Frist Name-Email Address-LastN |
Name1      | LName1    | Email1        | Name1Scrambled-Email1Scrambled |
Name2      | LName2    | Email2        |Etc.                            |
Etc.       | Etc.      | Etc.          |Etc.                            |   
Encryptedtextonnewrowatbottomoforiginaldataetc...|
```

Comment: using List.Add() is going to always add it to the end of the list. If you want to update an entry on a list you can do something like List[i] = List[i] + "," + encryptedTextAsBase64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing the `List` with the `string`. So let us try to break down your code:

```
 foreach (var contact in contacts)
 {
   Console.WriteLine($"{contact.FirstName},{contact.LastName},{contact.EmailAddress}");
   output.Add($"{contact.FirstName},{contact.LastName},{contact.EmailAddress},{contact.FirstName}-{contact.EmailAddress}-{contact.LastName}");
 }
```

In this foreach loop you are running through every contact and for each contact you are adding a string to the list of strings called `output`.

Now by calling:

```
output.Add(encryptedTextAsBase64);
```

At the end of your code and outside of the foreach loop you are now adding a new line to the list, that only contains the `encryptedTextAsBase64`.

So instead of adding it in the end of your list you want to add it in the end of every line. So we have to jump back into your `foreach` loop to do this:

```
 foreach (var contact in contacts)
 {
   Console.WriteLine($"{contact.FirstName},{contact.LastName},{contact.EmailAddress}");
   output.Add($"{contact.FirstName},{contact.LastName},{contact.EmailAddress},{contact.FirstName}-{contact.EmailAddress}-{contact.LastName},{encryptedTextAsBase64}");
 }
```

See how I added `encryptedTextAsBase64`to the end of the `output.Add(...)` line. This will ensure that you add the encrypted text in the end of every string and not in the end of your list.